# Hibernate SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000

Tags: java, hibernate

My hibernate query is like that.

```
@Override
    public List<Userdata> getUserDataWithUserType(String userName) {
        List<Userdata> africanContinents = getSession().createSQLQuery(
                "from userdata cont join cont.usertype ctry "
                + "where cont.userName = '" + userName + "")
                .list();
        return africanContinents;
    }
```

But when my method is running the system will give error message

```
SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
ERROR:   You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

How I solve that.
***Above code used for create join operation for two tables.
** myuserdata class is

```
@Entity
@Table(name="userdata")
public class Userdata  implements java.io.Serializable {
     private Integer userId;
     private Usertype usertype;
     private String firstName;
     private String lastName;
     private String userName;
     private String passWord;
     private String email;
     private String tleNo;
     private Date birthDay;
     private String department;
     private String image;
     private Boolean checkBy;

    public Userdata() {
    }


    public Userdata(Usertype usertype) {
        this.usertype = usertype;
    }


     //get set method
}
```

Comment: If you set _show\_sql_ hibernate property to _true_ you'll be able to see the SQL statement generated by Hibernate. Then try to run the statement by hands. It looks like you made mistake in your statement - you are missing single closing quote.
`cont.userName = ' " + userName + " ' "`

Answer (score 1):

When you use `createSQLQuery()` you are executing a raw SQL query on the underlying database.  However, the syntax you are using appears to be HQL, not raw SQL, so my guess is that you intended to use `createQuery()` instead of `createSQLQuery()`.  Try this code:

```
@Override
public List<Userdata> getUserDataWithUserType(String userName) {
    List<Userdata> africanContinents = getSession().createQuery(
        "from Userdata cont where cont.userName = :userName")
       .setParameter("userName", userName)
       .list();
    return africanContinents;
}
```

You will notice that I also used `setParameter` to set the parameter in the `WHERE` clause.  This is a precaution against SQL injection, and you should review the documentation on this.

Comment: Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[dispatcher]: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: userdata is not mapped

Comment: Post your `Userdata` class.

Comment: public class Userdata  implements java.io.Serializable {
     private Integer userId;
     private Usertype usertype;
     private String firstName;
     private String lastName;
     private String userName;
     private String passWord;

Comment: Update your question with the Hibernate entity code.  You are most likely missing an annotation somewhere.

Comment: @W.PraneethMadusanka Just replace `userdata` with `Userdata`. And you don't need a join for `cont.usertype`.

Answer (score 0):

> try this. Explanation will be added soon.

```
Query q = getSession().createQuery(
                "from userdata cont cont.usertype where cont.userName =: userName");
q.setParameter("userName","kumar");  

 List<Userdata> africanContinents  = query.list();
```

Comment: You don't need the join.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I Removed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also  got that  error  and issue  was , We  have  used  name "key" as a column  name .  So  what we  did  is   in our  entity  class  we have  used  "`"  with  the  column name  "key"  like  this

```
@Column(name = "`key`")
private String  key;
```